# Filter posts by categories ajax is showing nothing

Tags: categories, ajax, dropdown

I have used the following code, but nothing is showing when I select category from dropdown, page is this https://eakdigital.com/blog/

Template file

```
<div id="ajax-cases">
<?php
// WP Query
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'nopaging' => true, // show all posts in one go
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$tax = 'category';
$terms = get_terms( $tax, $args);
$count = count( $terms );
if ( $count > 0 ): ?>
<div class="post-tags">
<?php
echo '<select>';
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
$term_link = get_term_link( $term, $tax ); 
echo '<option value="' . $term_link . '" class="tax-filter" title="'.$term->slug.'">' . $term->name . '</option> ';
}
echo '</select>';
</div>
<?php endif; 
?></div>
<div class="tagged-posts">
//result must display here
</div>
```

JS file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
jQuery('.post-tags select').on('change', function(event) {


// Prevent default action - opening tag page
if (event.preventDefault) {
    event.preventDefault();
} else {
    event.returnValue = false;
}

// Get tag slug from title attirbute
var selecetd_taxonomy = jQuery(this).find('option:selected').attr("title");

// After user click on tag, fade out list of posts
jQuery('.tagged-posts').fadeOut();

data = {
    action: 'filter_posts', // function to execute
    afp_nonce: afp_vars.afp_nonce, // wp_nonce
    taxonomy: selecetd_taxonomy, // selected tag
    };

jQuery.post( afp_vars.afp_ajax_url, data, function(response) {

    if( response ) {
    alert(response);
        // Display posts on page
        jQuery('.tagged-posts').html( response );
        // Restore div visibility
        jQuery('.tagged-posts').fadeIn();
    };
});
});
});
```

Functions file

```
function ajax_filter_posts_scripts() {
// Enqueue script
wp_register_script('afp_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-filter-posts.js', false, null, false);
wp_enqueue_script('afp_script');

wp_localize_script( 'afp_script', 'afp_vars', array(
'afp_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'afp_nonce' ), // Create nonce which we later will use to verify AJAX request
'afp_ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
)
);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_filter_posts_scripts', 100);
function ajax_filter_get_posts( $taxonomy ) {

// Verify nonce
if( !isset( $_POST['afp_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['afp_nonce'], 'afp_nonce' ) )
die('Permission denied');

$taxonomy = $_POST['taxonomy'];

// WP Query
$args = array(

'post_type' => 'post',
'nopaging' => true, // show all posts in one go
);
echo $taxonomy;
// If taxonomy is not set, remove key from array and get all posts
if( !$taxonomy ) {
unset( $args['tag'] );
}else{
// This is the code which you are missing. You need to add taxonomy query if taxonomy is set.
$arg['tax_query']= array(
array(
'taxonomy' => 'category',
'field' => 'slug',
'terms' => array( $taxonomy ),
'include_children' => true, // set true if you want post of its child     category also
'operator' => 'IN'
),
);
}

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

$output  = '<h2><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'. get_the_title().'</a></h2>';
$output .= get_the_excerpt();

$result = 'success';

endwhile; else:
$output = '<h2>No posts found</h2>';
$result = 'fail';
endif;

$response = json_encode($output);
echo $response;
die();
}
```

Comment: Console log any errors? wp_debug on and reporting any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not told WP what to do with the AJAX request, add this line in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_filter_posts', 'ajax_filter_get_posts' );
```

and remove the `$taxonomy` parameter from `ajax_filter_get_posts` as it serves no purpose.

Comment: is there any way to load the results faster? It takes too long to display response via ajax.

Comment: you could fetch the minimum amount of data needed to construct the html on the client side, you could also implement some kind of paging, fetching and displaying n posts at a time so the client can see results loading sooner. you can also implement a caching mechanism so categories are loaded only the first time they are selected. or if it's not too slow and the data will not change, you could load all posts in js the first time you fetch the page and do away with ajax altogether.

Comment: I am fetching 10 posts in one go

Comment: you could also try using the rest api

Comment: can you please help me on that?

Comment: Also, if I remove
    if ( $count > 0 ):
condition, it does not show all categories.

Comment: please post a new question if you have further queries. for rest api, i have never implemented it but it looks fairly simple, just read up on it and you can always ask for help if you get stuck.